# I am not even using FlatButton or RaisedButton but i am getting these errors. I have searched my whole project. Also can't understand below errors too

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, agora.io

/C:/Users/Dell/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_platform_widgets-1.20.0/lib/src/platform_dialog_action.dart:171:14: Error: The method 'FlatButton' isn't defined for the class 'PlatformDialogAction'.

- 'PlatformDialogAction' is from 'package:flutter_platform_widgets/src/platform_dialog_action.dart' ('/C:/Users/Dell/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_platform_widgets-1.20.0/lib/src/platform_dialog_action.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'FlatButton'.
  return FlatButton(
  ^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/Users/Dell/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_platform_widgets-1.20.0/lib/src/platform_button.dart:269:14: Error: The method 'FlatButton' isn't defined for the class 'PlatformButton'.
- 'PlatformButton' is from 'package:flutter_platform_widgets/src/platform_button.dart' ('/C:/Users/Dell/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_platform_widgets-1.20.0/lib/src/platform_button.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'FlatButton'.
  return FlatButton(
  ^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/Users/Dell/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_platform_widgets-1.20.0/lib/src/platform_button.dart:302:12: Error: The method 'RaisedButton' isn't defined for the class 'PlatformButton'.
- 'PlatformButton' is from 'package:flutter_platform_widgets/src/platform_button.dart' ('/C:/Users/Dell/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_platform_widgets-1.20.0/lib/src/platform_button.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'RaisedButton'.
  return RaisedButton(
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/Users/Dell/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/agora_uikit-1.1.0/lib/controllers/rtm_client_event_handler.dart:76:7: Error: A value of type 'Null Function(LocalInvitation)' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'dynamic Function(LocalInvitation, String)?'.
- 'LocalInvitation' is from 'package:agora_rtm/src/utils.dart' ('/C:/Users/Dell/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/agora_rtm-1.5.5/lib/src/utils.dart').
  (AgoraRtmLocalInvitation invitation) {
  ^
  /C:/Users/Dell/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/agora_uikit-1.1.0/lib/controllers/rtm_client_event_handler.dart:81:7: Error: A value of type 'void Function(LocalInvitation)' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'void Function(LocalInvitation, String)?'.
- 'LocalInvitation' is from 'package:agora_rtm/src/utils.dart' ('/C:/Users/Dell/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/agora_rtm-1.5.5/lib/src/utils.dart').
  (AgoraRtmLocalInvitation invitation) {
  ^
  /C:/Users/Dell/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/agora_uikit-1.1.0/lib/controllers/rtc_event_handlers.dart:18:32: Error: No named parameter with the name 'onApiCallExecuted'.
  return RtcEngineEventHandler(onApiCallExecuted: (err, api, result) {
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/Users/Dell/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/agora_rtc_engine-6.2.0/lib/src/agora_rtc_engine.dart:1636:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const RtcEngineEventHandler({
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'D:\Flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1151
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'D:\Flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 25s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

can't get rid of these errors. Someone please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

it seems the plugin using the FlatButton,

try updating the plugin to the latest

```
agora_uikit: ^1.3.3


flutter_platform_widgets: ^3.3.5

OR

flutter_platform_widgets: ^4.0.0-beta.1
```

Comment: The FlatButton error did go away but agora one still shows up.

Answer (score 0):

- #### These errors are coming from `flutter_platform_widgets`.
- #### The ultimate solution will be updating this plugin to its latest version

## Happy Coding

Comment: The agora_uikit error is still showing even after updating the plugin to latest version